# Merge two-dimensional array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array, merge

I want to merge two two-dimensional array in perl.

For example, @array1 and @array2 are two-dimensional arrays. @array1 has 200 rows and 300 columns. @array2 has 200 rows and 100 columns. My question is that how can I merge or join these two arrays, so that I can a get a new array that has 200 rows and 400 columns, also I want to print each element of this new array. Is there a similar way in perl as the command "cbind" in R. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my @a1 = (
  # make one row with elements 1..300, and multiply/make 200 of these
  ([1..300]) x 200
);

my @a2 = (
  ([1..100]) x 200
);

my @r;
for my $i (0 .. $#a1) {
  # dereference $a1[$i] and $a2[$i] arrays,
  # merge them, and push into @r as new row
  push @r, [ @{ $a1[$i] }, @{ $a2[$i] } ];

  print "@{ $r[$i] }\n";
}

# use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@r;
```

Comment: One question is that I saw the output is space delimited file, I wonder is there any method can make it tab-delimited file. Thank you.

Comment: @user3674343  `print join("\t", @{ $r[$i] }), "\n";`

Comment: Thank you so much. You answered all my questions. Wish you have a great one.